# Perform action every time iframe re-navigates. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm making a bot for something, which is designed to move to the next 'page' of a file and search for a string, and to repeat this action until it's found that string. Everything works, in terms of searching for strings, however it only navigates to the next page once (so it only goes to online.php?page=2. I believe this is because the iframe.contentWindow.load is only triggering once, on the first run of the code. So when it moves to a new page, it's not continuing.

Any ideas?

```
document.body.innerHTML = '' //Out with the old
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var increm = 1
iframe.src = 'online.php?page=' + parseInt(increm)
iframe.style.height= '3000px'
iframe.style.width = '100%'
document.body.appendChild(iframe); //In with the new

$( iframe.contentWindow ).load(function() { //Once EVERYTHING has loaded
    runcode()
});

function runcode(){
    whole = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerText
    var sub = "StringToSearchFor";
    if(whole.indexOf(sub) > -1){ //If the string is found on the page
        console.log('The string has been found on this page')
    }else{ //Otherwise
        increm = increm+1
        iframe.src = 'online.php?page=' + parseInt(increm); //Move to the next page
        $( iframe.contentWindow ).load(function() { //rinse
            runcode() //repeat
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have 2 load handlers, one of which is inside your function, calling runcode() again.

You only need 1, but don't attach it to content that changes. Content removed means handler removed. So, do:

```
$( iframe ).load(function() { runcode() });
```

OR

```
$( iframe ).on("load", function() { runcode() });
```

OR

```
$( iframe ).on("load", ".newchilddiv", function() { runcode() });
```

EDIT: also innerText is causing an error

```
whole = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerText
```

Comment: I had no success with one handler (the first one) so I added the second to see if it would resolve, same results in both cases. I originally assumed that the first load handler would re-trigger every time the iframe re-navigated. Is there maybe a specific means by which I should re-navigate with the iframe, which isn't just changing the src?

Comment: try replace innerText with something else ;)

Comment: The innerText is how I'm searching through the body of the document to see if a specific string is matched. I could use innerHTML but I don't think it would make much of a difference...

Comment: Yeah think I was wrong about the handlers. Attach the load handler to something that doesn't change .. eg. the iframe itself

Comment: maybe .text or .textContent I'm not sure. innerText gave me an error which stopped the script... watch your console.log

Comment: textContent and innerText yield the same results, but I'll use the former - thanks. As for "attaching the handler to something that doesn't change", the purpose of the handler is to ensure the content within the iframe has loaded before moving on, what would you suggest instead? Thanks.

Comment: yeah, just attach it to something that doesn't change eg. the iframe or body or document... see updated answer